# while-else-loop

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, while-loop, theory

Of course this is an impossible statement in java (to-date), however ideally I would like to implement it as it is at the heart of many iterations. For example the first multiple times it is called I'm doing it 650,000+ times when it is creating the `ArrayList`.
Unfortunately the reality is that my actual code does not have the `set` inside the `else` loop; thus it will pass over both the `add` and then the `set` commands and wasting time.

After that I have it also in another loop where it is only performing the set as the data is already created and this is multi-nested with in many others so it is a lengthy process.

```
ArrayList<Integer>  dataColLinker = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
...
...
public void setLinkerAt( int value, int rowIndex) {
    ...
    while(rowIndex >= dataColLinker.size()) {
        dataColLinker.add(value);
    } else {
        dataColLinker.set(rowIndex, value);
    }
```

Any ideas or theories?
I'm unsure about speeds in java when it comes to `if` statements and `ArrayList` commands and so on

Comment: so you want to add the same value N times and then you want to change the `rowIndex` to value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Am I missing something?

Doesn't this hypothetical code

```
while(rowIndex >= dataColLinker.size()) {
    dataColLinker.add(value);
} else {
    dataColLinker.set(rowIndex, value);
}
```

mean the same thing as this?

```
while(rowIndex >= dataColLinker.size()) {
    dataColLinker.add(value);
}
dataColLinker.set(rowIndex, value);
```

or this?

```
if (rowIndex >= dataColLinker.size()) {
    do {
        dataColLinker.add(value);
    } while(rowIndex >= dataColLinker.size());
} else {
    dataColLinker.set(rowIndex, value);
}
```

(The latter makes more sense ... I guess).  Either way, it is obvious that you can rewrite the loop so that the "else test" is not repeated inside the loop ... as I have just done.

---

FWIW, this is most likely a case of premature optimization.  That is, you are probably wasting your time optimizing code that doesn't need to be optimized:

- For all you know, the JIT compiler's optimizer may have already moved the code around so that the "else" part is no longer in the loop.
- Even if it hasn't, the chances are that the particular thing you are trying to optimize is not a significant bottleneck ... even if it might be executed 600,000 times.

My advice is to forget this problem for now.  Get the program working.  When it is working, decide if it runs fast enough.  If it doesn't then profile it, and use the profiler output to decide where it is worth spending your time optimizing.

Comment: @Stephen I think that in a language like Python the else block is  executed only if the while condition is not initially met. I know this is Java, and we do not have that here, but this could be the origin of the question.

Comment: @Stephen, yes your first example is what I do have, but I want it to perform with less access as it will pass many times and here is passes through `add` and again through `set`. The second example looks like a good one, but I possible can know when I'm adding and changing the value, thus keeping it streamlines better... in to separate functions.  I don't know a sparse array??? basically this col is part of my `tableModel` and identifies linked rows, do you possibly have a different idea on tackling it?

Comment: @xchiltonx - I'm not going to advise you more on this because I suspect that you are wasting your time with premature optimization.   See my updated answer.

Comment: +1 for Stephen.  Trying to optimize this is a waste of your time.  If there's any ways to improve it, Java will find them itself.

Comment: Those examples are not the same. Every single one of em does a different thing. 1. If you look at it from a python perspective  in the first example the while body is executed and the else part will only be reached if there are no breaks. 2. The last statement will always be executed after the while loop. 3. The last statement will never be executed after the while loop. (Excluding exceptions) -- How on earth are these three example codes the same.

Comment: 1) I'm neither saying that they all mean the same thing; see  *"(The latter makes more sense ... I guess)"*.  How can A "make more sense" than B if A and B mean the same thing? 2) Java is sufficiently unlike Python that I don't think that analogies are valid.

Comment: Not really a good answer at all. The whole point is to avoid redundancy. We aren't perfectionists for nothing. See this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44475166/961018

Comment: In Java, the whole point is to write code that other people can read and maintain.

Comment: In Python, the `else` statement only executes if the loop exits normally, i.e., not breaking out of it. It's a niche feature, but it has its uses.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why there is a encapsulation of a while...

Use

```
//Use the appropriate start and end...
for(int rowIndex = 0, e = 65536; i < e; ++i){        
    if(rowIndex >= dataColLinker.size()) {
         dataColLinker.add(value);
     } else {
        dataColLinker.set(rowIndex, value);
     }    
}
```

Comment: Based on the `while - else` statement, it should be a `break` as last sentence inside the `else` code block.

Comment: Based on the fact the original question had an else clause coupled to the while I will not attempt to argue this however you may very well be correct

Comment: the number of elements is unknown

Comment: Not that that really matters... you could replace the i < e with some.hasNext() and get the same result I think... e.g. for(int i = 0; some.hasNext(); i = some.getNext())... but the answer above is probably correct anywho :P

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean entered = false, last;
while (( entered |= last = ( condition ) )) {
        // Do while
} if ( !entered ) {
        // Else
}
```

You'r welcome.

Comment: This is a pretty cryptic answer. Can you explain the logic here and show what it will look like for the code in the question? Although having multiple (non-trivial) assignments in the same statement (never mind in a loop condition) would, to me, be a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Calling variable first for 'whiled' or entered is possibly more clear here.

Comment: @Dukeling I am answering the question in the only way possible I can see in Java without redundant code for checks or extracting to a method for a call to check the recheck the condition. Anyhow, the principle is basically that last is always checked and set against the condition, which is the one actually required to be true to enter the while loop. then you have entered |= ... which is an OR with 'entered' self, so anytime last, or the condition is true, whether on first check or subsequent checks, entered will always be true which is then checked in the if block right after.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the "set" statement to mean "set if not set" and put it naked above the while loop.

You are correct, the language does not provide what you're looking for in exactly that syntax, but that's because there are programming paradigms like the one I just suggested so you don't need the syntax you are proposing.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have this control structure.
It should be noted though, that other languages do.
Python for example, has the [while-else](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=while#the-while-statement) construct.

In Java's case, you can mimic this behaviour as you have already shown:

```
if (rowIndex >= dataColLinker.size()) {
    do {
        dataColLinker.add(value);
    } while(rowIndex >= dataColLinker.size());
} else {
    dataColLinker.set(rowIndex, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This while else statement should only execute the else code when the condition is false, this means it will always execute it. But, there is a catch, when you use the break keyword within the while loop, the else statement should not execute.

The code that satisfies does condition is only:

```
boolean entered = false;
while (condition) {
   entered = true; // Set it to true stright away
   // While loop code


   // If you want to break out of this loop
   if (condition) {
      entered = false;
      break;
   }
} if (!entered) {
   // else code
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better if I or someone programs a while-else-loop object :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are coming from Python and accept this as the same thing:

```
def setLinkerAt(value, rowIndex):
    isEnough = lambda i: return i < dataColLinker.count()
    while (not isEnough(rowIndex)):
        dataColLinker.append(value)
    else:
        dataColLinker[rowIndex] = value
```

The most similar I could come up with was:

```
public void setLinkerAt( int value, int rowIndex) {
    isEnough = (i) -> { return i < dataColLine.size; }
    if(isEnough()){
        dataColLinker.set(rowIndex, value);
    }
    else while(!isEnough(rowInex)) {
        dataColLinker.add(value);
    }
```

Note the need for the logic, and the reverse logic. I'm not sure this is a great solution (duplication of the logic), but the braceless `else` is the closest syntax I could think of, while maintaining the same act of not executing the logic more than required.