# While else statement equivalent for Java?

Tags: java, python, if-statement, while-loop

What is the Java equivalent of the while/else in Python? Because it doesn't work in Java. The first chunk was my python code and the second portion is my attempt to translate it into Java. **Edit: tring to replicate while-else**

```
  while temp.frontIsClear():
    if temp.nextToABeeper():
       temp.pickBeeper()
       count += 1
    temp.move()
 else:
    if temp.nextToABeeper():
       temp.pickBeeper()
       count += 1
 print "The count is ", count
```

Java Attempt

```
  Robot temp = new Robot();
  int count = 0;
  while (temp.frontIsClear())
  {
     if (temp.nextToABeeper())
     {
        temp.pickBeeper();
        count += 1;
     }
     temp.move();
  }
  else
  {
     if (temp.nextToABeeper())
     {
        temp.pickBeeper();
        count += 1;
     }
  }
  print ("The count is ", count);
```

Comment: there isn't such a thing in Java, you will just have to do if(!temp.frontIsClear()) instead of the else

Comment: Your python code is broken anyway, since the while block doesn't contain a break.

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing in Python, but I don't see the point of it. How is `white(){..} else {code}` different from `while(){..}; code`?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The top answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) gives an answer to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while-else-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791030/while-else-loop)

Comment: @Bubletan: Not a good dupe. People trying to replicate the behavior of Python's while-else won't find anything useful there.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the given example, the else statement on the `while` loop is pointless as nothing ever `break`s out of the `while` loop.  The given python could equivalently be written with the content of the `else` block moved one level higher.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The closest Java equivalent is to explicitly keep track of whether you exited the loop with a `break`... but you don't actually *have* a `break` in your code, so using a while-else was pointless in the first place.

For Java folks (and Python folks) who don't know what Python's while-else does, an `else` clause on a `while` loop executes if the loop ends without a `break`. Another way to think about it is that it executes if the `while` condition is false, just like with an `if` statement.

A while-else that actually had a `break`:

```
while whatever():
    if whatever_else():
        break
    do_stuff()
else:
    finish_up()
```

could be translated to

```
boolean noBreak = true;
while (whatever()) {
    if (whateverElse()) {
        noBreak = false;
        break;
    }
    doStuff();
}
if (noBreak) {
    finishUp();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use one more if statement:

```
if (temp.nextToABeeper())
    // pick beer
} else {
    while (temp.frontIsClear()) { /* your code */ }
}
```

Or:

```
if (temp.frontIsClear())
    while (temp.frontIsClear()) { /* your code */ }
} else if (temp.nextToABeeper()) {
    // pick beer
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Java [Backus–Naur form Grammar](https://users-cs.au.dk/amoeller/dRegAut/JavaBNF.html) (Syntax Specification), `else` never follows a `while`.

Your solution needs to be modified accordingly. You can put the `while` in an `else`, that way you handle the `if` statement.

```
if temp.nextToBeeper() {
     //handle
 } else {
      while(temp.frontIsClear()) {
         //handle
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Robot temp = new Robot();
int count = 0;

if (temp.frontIsClear())
{
  while (temp.frontIsClear())
  {
     if (temp.nextToABeeper())
     {
        temp.pickBeeper();
        count += 1;
     }
     temp.move();
  }
} 
else if (temp.nextToABeeper())
{
   temp.pickBeeper();
   count += 1;
}
print ("The count is ", count);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java

`if` is a conditional statement .

But

`while` is `loop` that is iterate again an again and stop itself when `false`condition occurred .